# Difference between String[] and Vector{String}[] in Julia

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
x = String[]
y = Vector{String}[]

x == y  # is true

push!(x, "a")  # works fine
push!(y, "a")  # ERROR
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Vector{String}
```

What is the difference between `String[]` and `Vector{String}[]`? Aren't they both vectors of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T[]` where `T` is a type generates a zero-length vector with elements of type `T`. So your `y` is a vector of `Vector{String}`s. Therefore if you try to push Strings to it you get an error. Try pushing a vector of Strings.

Comment: Oh, so the equality was just because both vectors were empty?

Comment: Yes, `==` only checks values, not types.